# VSCode Update 1.70 to 1.71 issues

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode new update 1.71 is available. I currently have VSCode 1.70
I download the .deb package for ubuntu and VSCode will not update.
Similar questions have been asked and most popular response is to do the following:
`sudo apt-get update` after that i run the following `sudo apt-get update code`
computer than tells me `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
code is already the newest version (1.70.2-1660629410)`
Help Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update code
```

`update` does not accept anything behind it.

If you download a .deb you need to use `dpkg` to install it, not `apt`. `apt` will only update from the repositories. That would be:

```
sudo dpkg --install {package.db}
```

You will also  need to take care of dependencies if there are any.

Other method using `apt`:

To get 1.72 you can use this to add a key, add the 3rd party ppa from microsoft, and update/upgrade to the newest version:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
sudo apt update
```

and for 1.72 you install it with

```
sudo apt install code-insider
```

or 1.71 with

```
sudo apt install code
```

That method will also add newer version when those get released.

Comment: this worked perfect. Thank you for your time! Sorry about my late response. I got called into work. Problem solved. both solutions above work!!

Comment: no problem @SamMorrison Good to hear you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing up two different levels here. `apt` works with repositories that are defined in your `sources.list` (and accompanying files). Those repositories contain `deb` packages. But that doesn't mean that `apt` knowns about any `deb` packages that you downloaded and stored somewhere on your file system ;)

There are basically two things you can do. The first way, which I would recomend, is to wait until the the repository you installed the `code` package originally from has updated to the 1.71 version. Then, the new version should appear in your updates automatically.

The second way is to install the `deb` file you've downloaded manually with `dpkg`. But this way, you are responsible for any depedencies, incompatibilities and so forth yourself.

Comment: first answer in the thread solved the problem. thank you for your time